# Cargar usuario logueado de la base de datos al hacer petición en Asp Net core

Tags: asp.net, mvc, api, controller

Des del controlador de la API de la base de datos cojo la ID del Usuario que se ha logeado, el problema es que al coger todo el usuario el dbcontext lo detecta como uno nuevo, y al insertarlo en savechanges me da excepcion por clave duplicada ya que ese usuario ya existe en la base de datos.

```
ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(User);

UsuarioActivitats ua = new UsuarioActivitats(){
                    Activitat = activitat,
                    Usuario = user
                };

dbContext.UsuarioActivitats.Add(ua);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

dbContext Controlador:

```
public GuardarInformacion(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
            UserManager = userManager;
            dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
}
```

Por que motivo el dbcontext me detecta ese usuario como nuevo? Como puedo resolver este caso? gracias.

Mis soluciones serian que puedo marcar el usuario como no modificado ( y referencias la línia ) pero me parece una solución poco elegante o también puedo volver a cargar el usuario des de la base de datos, pero me parece también poco elegante.

Comment: victor, solucionó la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/168011/46148) tu pregunta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muy posiblemente el motivo sea que el UserManager carga el usuario desde un dbcontext que no es el tuyo. Tu dbcontext es este:

```
dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
```

Mi recomendación es que pruebes a usar el dbcontext que te inyecta el controlador. En el artículo [ASP.NET Core: Injecting your DB Context into your Controllers](https://jessedotnet.com/2016/12/29/asp-net-core-injecting-your-db-context-into-your-controllers/) está bastante bien explicado:

1) Inyectar el dbcontext en el `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    // Add User DB connection
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
     options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));


    ..........

}
```

2) Recoger el dbcontext en el controlador

```
public class GentController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _manager; 

    public GentController(ApplicationDbContext context, 
                          UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        _context = context;
        _manager = manager;  
    }

    ...

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Nom,Cognoms,Perfil")] 
                                     Persona persona)
    {
        var user = await _manager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            persona.Created_by = user;
            _context.Add(persona);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(persona);
    }
```

Prueba si de esta manere el UserManager utiliza la misma instancia de dbcontext que el controdor para recoger el usuario. Si es así ya detectará que lo ha pillado de la base de datos y que existe. Si no es así buscamos otra solución. A mi de esta manera me funciona perfectamente.